# Sparse GPR estimation in GPflow with Tensorflow's adam optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpflow

Are there any code examples of using an Adam optimizer with sparse estimation (e.g. `SVGP` or `SGPR`) in GPflow. I could not immediately find any examples and it wasn't immediately obvious on how to pass data (e.g. `X` and `Y`) to the model since the update to GPflow 2.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of very helpful Jupyter notebooks in the [GPFlow repository](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/tree/develop/doc/source/notebooks) itself, which are also rendered in the online [docs](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/). These have numerous examples. For instance, here is a notebook for [using Adam in SVGP](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/gps_for_big_data.html) in the latest release of GPflow.